# primefaces ajax update of panel from another form

Tags: java, ajax, jsf-2, primefaces, panel

I have some code here:

```
<f:view>
    <h:form id="formA">
        <p:treeTable id="tree">
            <p:ajax event="select" listener="..." update="mustRefresh" />  
            ...
        </p:treeTable>
    </h:form>
    <h:form id="formB">
        <p:panel id="mustRefresh"> ... </p:panel>

    </h:form>   
</f:view>
```

When user select a record on treeTable(formA), its detail will show on formB and ready to edit. My trouble is update="mustRefresh" not work, it throw exception like this:

```
javax.faces.FacesException: Cannot find component with identifier "mustRefresh" referenced from "A4578:formA:tree".
```

I tried with @form, formB, :formB and :mustRefresh but it does not work.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Since `mustRefresh` in the component hierarchy is inside `formB` you should reference it with:

```
<p:ajax event="select" listener="..." update=":formB:mustRefresh" />
```

See how [UIComponentBase.findComponent](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponentBase.html#findComponent%28java.lang.String%29) works.

Comment: What if mustRefresh is not inside of formB? In my case, I should not to put mustRefresh component inside a Form element. I am calling it as `update=":mustRefresh"`, however it cannot find and refresh element.

Answer (score 17):

Use `update="@([id$=mustRefresh])"` -- this will pick up displayPost directly. There is no need to map it to anything.

Comment: this is the easiest solution

Comment: this worked better for me, thanks !!

Comment: this one is really easy and convenient...

Comment: Best way to update, instance of @(.ID_ELEMENT)