# p:dataTable no records found

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, jsf-2.2

I have a data table in a dialog.

When user clicked on the `Detail` link, the dialog with a data table should be displayed.

Here is the code:

```
<h:form>
   <h:dataTable value="#{messageBean.messagesList}" var="msg">

<h:column>
     <f:facet name="header">Detail</f:facet>
     <p:commandLink action="#{messageBean.fetchSelectedMessage(msg.msgId)}" value="#{msg.summary}" />
        </h:column>
   </h:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

And this is `messageBean.fetchSelectedMessag(...)`:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class MessageBean {

...
private List<Messages> messagesList;
private List<Messages> selectedMessage;

public void fetchSelectedMessage(String msgId) {
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE msgId=?";
    selectedMessage = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new Object[]{msgId}, new BeanPropertyRowMapper<Messages>(Messages.class));
    System.out.println("fetched selected message== " + selectedMessage); //correct
    //open dialog sucucessfully
    RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
    context.execute("PF('dlg1').show();");
}
//getter/setters
```

Then this dialog should opens (and open successfully, but displays nothing)

```
<p:dialog widgetVar="dlg1" modal="true" height="100">
    <p:dataTable var="msg1" value="#{messageBean.selectedMessage}">

        <p:column headerText="id">
            <h:outputText value="#{msg1.msgId}"/>
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="to person">
            <h:outputText value="#{msg1.toPerson}"/>
        </p:column>

    </p:dataTable>

</p:dialog>
```

Why the dialog data table can't show any thing?

the `selectedMessage` is a list of `messages` type and is not null.

Comment: Usually the dialog has already been drawn on page load, it's just hidden, so you still need to AJAX update it if the model changes. Adding an `update` to your commandLink might fix it.

Comment: @DavidS Like this?  `update="PF('dlg1').show();"`

Comment: No, the update attribute must match a component ID on the page. You will want to learn more about this, as it's an essential part of using AJAX with JSF. Here is an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14227681/primefaces-ajax-update-of-panel-from-another-form.

Comment: And BalusC wrote a good guide here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634156/cannot-find-component-with-expression-foo-referenced-from-bar-fajax-con.

Comment: @DavidS is right. Start with some basic jsf/ajax tutorials before diving into the deep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the dialog after each click:

```
<p:commandLink ... process="@this" update=":msgForm:dlgPanel" onComplete="PF('dlg1').show();"/>
```